# Axios get request is failing in my React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm catching error of failed axios get request to a .Net API but can't figure out how to make this API work. It's working perfectly fine in Postman and even directly in the Web Browser.

```
index.js:1472 {"status":404,"config":{"url":"http://iis-local-app-url/api/employee/getAll","method":"get",
"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"transformRequest":[null],
"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN",
"xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1}}
```

Here is the function calling the API

```
  let apiRes = null;
  try {
    apiRes = await axios.get(`iis-local-app-url/api/employee/getAll`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error response:");
    console.error(JSON.stringify(err.response));    // ***
    console.error(err.response.status);  // ***
    console.error(err.response.headers); // ***
  } finally {
    console.log(apiRes);
  }
```

I'm using axios mock for data display.

**Is there any problem with using mock and real API at the same time?**

**Or is it something CORS policy?**

Comment: write the full url : `await axios.get ("http://iis-local-app-url/api/employee/getAll")`

Comment: You got a 404 error, it means that the page doesn't exist.
So like Ali said, the problem is the URL. Try to read about HTTP Status Codes, its will help you a lot to understand your future requests.

Comment: @Ali I'm not getting what you mean.

Comment: Write full URL here
 apiRes = await axios.get("http://iis-local-app-url/api/employee/getAll"); not axios.get(`iis-local-app-url/api/employee/getAll`);

Comment: I intentionally added a url hint because I know it's irrelevant to the problem to write the full url. When url is working in Postman and don't require any heasers like Bearer token etc, then it should work in my client app as well.

Comment: One more thing, projects of Web API and client app are separate in the same solution.

Comment: iss-local-app-url the url of app deployed on iis and working perfectly fine with swagger, postman and directly hiting a url in the browser

Comment: `"http://iis-local-app-url/api/employee/getAll"` is the URL you need to use in `axios`.
:::important : `http://`:::     
and also try using this URL in the browser it should not throw 404.

Comment: @Sheelpriy I'm using this with http:// and I have tried this in browser, it's working perfectly fine